# Is it possible to sort iTunes U other than "Released Date"?

Tags: itunes, itunes-u

In iTunes > Library > iTunes U, the items are sorted by Released Date. How can I sort the items, say, by Name?

Comment: Are you talking about inside the App on an iDevice, or in iTunes on a computer?

Comment: @KatieK: I have the same problem - even stumped the "Geniuses".  Best answer I found was in Apple Support Forums that say to create a playlist, which you can sort

Answer (score 1):

Sorting by "Release Date" is currently the only option for sorting iTunes U in iTunes.

The sorting of content is meant to be left up to the creator of the iTunes U collection/course.

The collections are automatically sorted alphabetically by collection name. If you click on the disclosure triangle for each collection, the lectures can then be sorted by release date in ascending or descending order.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way around this problem is to create a play list in the add + playlist. Add the relevant tracks then sort by name. If you find that some of the tracks are not named correctly then just rename i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2, 2.1 etc